# holding variables in session scope without making them static?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, scope, java-ee-6

This is a rookie question, sorry.

I developed a jsf-2 app (on Tomcat) which has a big controller bean declared in session scope.

Now, the mistake I made was to put all session scoped variables in this bean as *static* variables, thinking they would not be shared between different instances of the app. But they are - static variables are shared across all instances of the app on a same JVM, which makes sense actually. Anyway, all my code is currently like that:

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean
public ControllerBean{
static private String aString = "session wide value for a string";
//static getter and setter for astring

}

@viewscoped
@ManagedBean
public class OneRandomViewScopedBean{
String oneString = ControllerBean.getAString();
//operations on this string...
ControllerBean.setAString(newValueForString);
}
```

Could I get pointers as to how I should refactor my code to remove the static variables in my ControllerBean? I suppose the solution is dead simple but I can't see it now.

Note: I don't need to persist the data because the volumes are small and they can vanish after the app is closed

Thx!

Comment: What is your target? Why are those variables declared as static? Why can't you just remove the static-keyword?

Comment: @Fant: because he can't figure a way to grab the current instance of the session scoped bean in order to get/set its properties. The answer is already given: use `@ManagedProperty`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `static` modifier (that was indeed a huge mistake; this problem is not JSF specific, but just basic Java. I'd really invest some more time in learning basic Java before continuing with JSF) and use [`@ManagedProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html) to inject other beans or its properties.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ControllerBean {

    private String aString = "session wide value for a string";
    // Non-static getter and setter for aString.

    // ...
}

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class OneRandomViewScopedBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{controllerBean}")
    private ControllerBean controllerBean;
    // Setter for controllerBean. Getter is not mandatory.

    public void someAction() {
        controllerBean.setAString(newValueForString);
    }

    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Injecting managed beans in each other](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#InjectingManagedBeansInEachOther)